# What version of Bluetooth does the Echo Show 5 support?

Tags: consumer-electronics

Title says it all. I can’t find the Bluetooth version, only that it supports Bluetooth. Also, forgive me if this question is off topic here.

Comment: I think Echo Show 5 only supports blue tooth classic, aka audio. If you thinking BLE connectivity for data, Echo show 5 might not have support.This because the system is using [MT8163V/A Highly integrated 64-bit quad-core tablet platform](https://www.mediatek.com/products/tablets/mt8163) processor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth 4.2 + EDR.

From Bestbuy: [Amazon Echo Show 5 Smart Display with Alexa - Charcoal](https://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/product/amazon-echo-show-5-smart-display-with-alexa-charcoal/13619574)

EDR is Enhanced Data Rate which means it is backwards compatible to other versions that implement EDR (2.1 + EDR & 2.0 + EDR).  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Bluetooth_4.2)